# recursive sass in depth

Tags: sass, mixins

I want to adapt padding like this.

it is possible to solve using sass mixin or another way

```
.list {

  .item {
    .text-box {
        padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

.list {

    .item {
       .text-box {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
   }

   .list {

       .item {
            .text-box {
                padding-left: 30px;
            }

        }

        .list {

            .item {
                .text-box {
                    padding-left: 40px;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What about a loop with `@for` directive?

```
$list: ".list";
@for $i from 0 through 3 {
  #{$list} {
    .item {
      .text-box {
        padding-left: (10px + $i*10px);
      }
    }
  }
  $list: append($list, ".list");
}
```